# Kafka: Preventing deletion of reprocessed past events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an `events` topic with full retention, so I can reprocess at any point. I am using KafkaStreams to process this data (includes sessioning). There are many output topics that are sent to a database.

I have a TimestampExtractor which sets the timestamp of the Kafka record to that of the original event, so as to perform windowing over the data among other things.

However, in the output topics of the processing, I have set up weeks-long retention policies (so they are deleted after they are consumed).

If I reprocess this data from the original topic, the timestamps generated in the output topics may be older than the threshold of the retention policy - so they may be marked for deletion.

Since when they are published they are eligible for retention, how could I prevent them from deletion? How to separate different timestamps for data retention from data processing? Is it *almost-mandatory* to use "wall clock time" timestamps on output topics subject to retention?

Comment: Can you not put the timestamp within the record value or header instead?

Comment: I could, and I have actually... but AFAIK, for windowing, you need to use that record timestamp. E.g. window over pageviews to create sessions, while keeping pageviews and sessions as output topics. In this scenario pageviews topic is consumed to go to DB, and also for the sessioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "right" solution would be to set higher retention time for the output topics. If your downstream applications consume this data, you might want to use "purge data" request (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-107%3A+Add+deleteRecordsBefore%28%29+API+in+AdminClient) to delete old data manually.

As an alternative, you could manipulate the timestamps for the **output records** only. You will need to upgrade to Kafka 2.0 (will be released soon): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-251%3A+Allow+timestamp+manipulation+in+Processor+API

Comment: Thanks for the help. Re: **"right solution"** - it would be an overkill. "Purge data" could be an option, although it should be automated in a custom script that validates last offset somehow, e.g. actual consumption on target DB and use sth like min(intended_deletion_date, last committed offset). Re. **Output Records Timestamp**: Change timestamp for output records only - if I just use a TimestampExtractor and having custom "OutputObjectTypes" just for output topics, and make the TimestampExtractor get the timestamp I want - wouldn't KafkaStreams honor that timestamp selection?

Comment: If data is consumed with Kafka Streams, it will honor whatever `TimestampExtractor` returns for source input records and those timestamps propagate to downstream/intermediate records -- with the new feature, you can change the timestamp for downstream intermediate records though and "overwrite" whatever `TimestampExtractor` returned.

Comment: I see. Following on the API, wouldn't it be nice to have a  `Produced.withTimestampExtractor(TimestampExtractor)` too ?

Comment: So far, timestamp manipulation is not exposed at DSL level: you would need to do a `stream.transform(...).to(...)` and set the timestamp within the `Transformer` -- I am personally not sure, if we should expose it at DSL level, because the DSL provides a semantic contract that is base on timestamps and changing the timestamps would "violate" the contract -- however, it's an open source project and anyone can suggest new features -- feel free to start a discussion on the dev mailing list about it :)